# Non invasive way for a debug print into ram file

Tags: c

I'm looking for a non invasive way of writing a local variable into a file to use it as a debugging mechanism. The non invasive part means that the debug code should have as little execution time as possible and should minimally interfere with the method that's being debugged.

Example:

Somewhere deep inside the code there is a `method`.

```
unsigned int method(short *frame, int length)
    {
    process-frame(short *frame, int length);
    }
```

It gets called 100 times a second and I would like to print out the content of `frame`. Since the process is time sensitive I can't print to the terminal but will print into the file in ram. Am looking for a way to do it inside the function scope.

Comment: What is a "ram file"?

Comment: @user2864740 A file created in ramfs.

Comment: So how does it differ from a "normal file"?

Comment: It doesn't, it just makes the process less invasive for the function being debugged which is one of the attributes I'm looking in the mechanism.

Comment: How is it 'less invasive' from a *code* point of view? Eg. isn't the question just "How can I write to a file?" - I'm fairly certain that is already covered.

Comment: True, but I'm aiming that the result is simple enough that it can be syntactically  equal for both languages.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the data is securely written to the file before 'method' returns?

Comment: @user2864740 No, it is about a way of writing to a file for debug purposes in a context when printing can't be done. The non invasive part means that the debug code should have as little execution time as possible and should minimally interfere with the method that's being debugged.

Comment: @MartinJames Nope, it would be great if the content could be buffered and executed less often.

Comment: @Alan in that case, is is feasible to copy the data to a malloced struct and queue off the pointer to another thread that handles the, possibly high-latency, file operations?

Comment: @MartinJames My current belief is that the file operations aren't high latency (do to the file existing in ram). The multi threaded example would probably work, but I'm exploring the situation for a reusable and hopefully simple copy-paste debugging solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I've come so far is this. Am open for other answers with a more optimized approach

```
unsigned int method(short *frame, int length)
    {
    static FILE * rawPcmLog; 
    if (rawPcmLog == NULL) rawPcmLog = fopen("/tmp/rawPcm","w"); 
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<length; i++){
        fwrite(frame,length, 1,rawPcmLog);
    }
    process-frame(short *frame, int length);
    }
```

Comment: You open the file every time you enter 'method', but never close it?  You are overwriting file descriptors.

Comment: Isn't `static` preventing that? My perspective was that it's opened only the first time and later the same pointer for `rawPcmLog` is used every time `method` is executed.

Comment: As it contains a function call, it will not be optimised away, even if the pointer is static. You should use the fact that a static pointer is initialized to NULL and write `static FILE * rawPcmLog; if (rawPcmLog == NULL) rawPcmLog = fopen("/tmp/rawPcm","w");`